# SAPUI5 | OPENUI5 Model Binding doesn't work

Tags: data-binding, binding, sapui5, model-binding

I have a `vertical layout` with 4 possible `input fields` like `<Input/>, <DatePicker/>, <Checkbox/>` and `<DateTimePicker/>`. When I bind the `value` of `Input, DateTimePicker or DatePicker` to `"{thingDetail>value}"` it works like it should. When I try to bind the `selected` part in my `checkbox` to `"{thingDetail>value}"` the `checkbox` is always checked, even if my `JSONModel` says the value is `"false"`.

```
                    <layout:VerticalLayout
                    width="100%"
                    visible="{= ! ${path: 'thingDetail>properties'}}">
                        <Input
                                id="masterDataValueInput"
                                value="{thingDetail>value}"
                                placeholder="{path:'thingDetail>type', formatter:'.formatter.placeHolderFormatter'}"
                                visible="{= ${path: 'thingDetail>type', formatter: '.formatter.inputVisibility'}}"
                                enabled="{appView>/isCurrentTenant}"
                                width="100%"
                                type="{path:'thingDetail>type', formatter:'.formatter.inputTypeFormatter'}"/>
                        <DatePicker
                                id="masterDataValueDate"
                                value="{thingDetail>value}"
                                visible="{= ${path: 'thingDetail>type', formatter: '.formatter.dateVisibility'}}"
                                enabled="{appView>/isCurrentTenant}"
                                width="100%"/>
                        <DateTimePicker
                                id="masterDataValueDateTime"
                                value="{thingDetail>value}"
                                visible="{= ${path: 'thingDetail>type', formatter: '.formatter.datetimeVisibility'}}"
                                enabled="{appView>/isCurrentTenant}"
                                width="100%"/>
                        <CheckBox
                                id="masterDataValueCheckbox" 
                                selected="{thingDetail>value}"
                                visible="{= ${path: 'thingDetail>type', formatter: '.formatter.checkboxVisibility'}}" 
                                enabled="{appView>/isCurrentTenant}"/>
                    </layout:VerticalLayout>
```

This is my `JSONModel` when I log it.
[image: This is my Model]

My `view` looks like this:
[image: view]
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Nervermind.. `TwoWayDataBinding` isn't possible with a `formatter`. The mistake was the `data type`.

With the following code it works:

```
                            <CheckBox
                                id="masterDataValueCheckbox" 
                                selected="{path: 'thingDetail>value', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String'}"
                                visible="{= ${path: 'thingDetail>type', formatter: '.formatter.checkboxVisibility'}}" 
                                enabled="{appView>/isCurrentTenant}"/>
```